# Samsung A50 Stuck on Samsung logo

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, data-recovery, boot-loop

This is Samsung A50 A505F, bought 4 years ago. Yesterday, it was showing full-storage warning because around 700MB was left from total internal space. There was no SD card. The same day, it restarted, got through the initial model-name splash screen, but stuck on "SAMSUNG" logo screen.

Pressing Power key for more than 15 seconds doesn't turn off the phone. If I press Vol Down and Power button for like 7 seconds, it restarts but gets stuck at the same page again. To turn off the device, I connect it with a charging socket, and then do Vol Down + Power again. This time, it powers off, and starts showing charging UI when the phone is off. If I remove the charging connector, device appears powered off.

I am able to get into Download Mode (VolUp + VolDown + USB connect) and Recovery Mode (VolUp + Power + USB Connect). **My suspicion is that this is being caused by Storage being full. Although, there's no such message or indication on Recovery Mode.** I am able to start ADB in sideload mode.

I have tried using Wipe Cache Partition and Repair Apps several times. I am not able to get into safe mode (either I am using wrong method or it doesn't work).

**Another technical detail is it showed some failed recovery logs (yesterday). Something about an exception with `RulesManagerService` on its `onStart` function. But, it no-longer shows those logs now.**

Is there any way I can get it working again without sacrificing my precious data? Or Can I recover the data somehow? I remember the lock-screen password pattern and connected email account credentials.

I am attaching some screenshots to show stuff:

charging-indication

[image: Charging]

model-name screen (not stuck)

[image: model-name]

stuck screen logo

[image: stuck]

download-mode

[image: download]

recovery-mode

[image: recovery]

Comment: You can always try to hard reset the phone by performing a factory data reset to see if that will fix the issue.

Comment: @DongLi Yes, I understand that will definitely fix this issue. However, I am interested in a way where I can save the onboard data as mentioned in the question.

Comment: You can do `adb pull /sdcard/file.ext  %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file.ext` to copy on your pc and then `adb shell rm sdcard/download/file.ext` to delete the file. Do this for 1, 2 big files. It should boot again. By the way the term is bootloop. After booting up you must clear storage and find if it was some app (sometime app's logs too do this) or just the storage which caused the bootloop